# Using pointers with binary trees

Tags: c, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Binary tree - Dereferencing pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11501016/binary-tree-dereferencing-pointers)

I was just trying to write a simple binary search tree program where the user can insert nodes and view all the nodes in the tree in either inorder,preorder or postorder mode. My code is

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct treenode
{
int data;
struct treenode *lchild;
struct treenode *rchild;
};

void insertnode(struct treenode **n,int d)
{
struct treenode *p=&n;
if(p==NULL)
{
    // means the tree is empty
    p=(struct treenode *)malloc(sizeof(struct treenode));
    p->data=d;
    p->lchild=NULL;
    p->rchild=NULL;
}

else
{
    // strat comparing the new data from root
    if( d<p->data )
        insertnode(((p->lchild)),d);

    else
        insertnode(((p->rchild)),d);
}
}

void preorder(struct treenode **n)
{
struct treenode *p=&n;
if(p==NULL)
{
    printf("\nThe list is empty");
}

else
{
    printf("%d",p->data);
    preorder(p->lchild);
    preorder(p->rchild);
}

}

void postorder(struct treenode **n)
 {
struct treenode *p=&n;
if(p==NULL)
{
    printf("\nThe list is empty");
}

else
{
    preorder(p->lchild);
    preorder(p->rchild);
    printf("%d",p->data);
}

}

void inorder(struct treenode **n)
{
struct treenode *p=&n;
if(p==NULL)
{
    printf("\nThe list is empty");
}

else
{
    preorder(p->lchild);
    printf("%d",p->data);
    preorder(p->rchild);
}

}

int main(void)
{
struct treenode *root=NULL;
int choice,data;

while(1)
{
    printf("\nPress 1 for inserting a node in BST fashion: ");
    printf("\nPress 2 for traversing the tree in preorder fashion :");
    printf("\nPress 3 for traversing the tree in postorder fashion :");
    printf("\nPress 4 for traversing the tree in inorder fashion :");
    printf("\nPress 5 to exit :");


    printf("\nEnter your choice: ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    switch(choice)
    {
        case 1: printf("\nEnter the data to be inserted:");
            scanf("%d",&data);
            insertnode(&root,data);
            break;

        case 2: preorder(&root);
            break;

        case 3: postorder(&root);
            break;

        case 4: inorder(&root);
            break;

        case 5: exit(0);
            break;

        default: printf("\nYou have enetred an invalid choice. Please try again");
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

---

The program runs successfully, however after i have entered the node, the explorer detects an error and the program stops working. Is there any bug in the code ?

Comment: Why don't you debug to know? Also what do you mean by "explorer"?

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/q/11501016/905902

Comment: Yeah.. i know but even after all the correction, my code isn't running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spoiler:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct treenode {
    struct treenode *lchild;
    struct treenode *rchild;
    int data;
    } *root = NULL;

void insertnode(struct treenode **pp,int d)
{
    for( ;*pp; )
    {
         if (d < (*pp)->data) pp = &(*pp)->lchild;
         else  pp = &(*pp)->rchild;
    }
    *pp = malloc (sizeof **pp);
    (*pp)->data = d;
    (*pp)->lchild = NULL;
    (*pp)->rchild = NULL;
}

void preorder(struct treenode *p)
{
    if(p==NULL)
    {
        printf("\nThe list is empty");
        return;
    }

    printf("%d,",p->data);
    if (p->lchild) preorder(p->lchild);
    if (p->rchild) preorder(p->rchild);
}

void postorder(struct treenode *p)
{
    if(p==NULL)
    {
        printf("\nThe list is empty");
        return;
    }

    if (p->lchild) preorder(p->lchild);
    if (p->rchild) preorder(p->rchild);
    printf("%d,",p->data);
}
void inorder(struct treenode *p)
{
    if(p==NULL)
    {
        printf("\nThe list is empty");
        return;
    }

    if (p->lchild) preorder(p->lchild);
    printf("%d,",p->data);
    if (p->rchild) preorder(p->rchild);
}

int main(void)
{
    root=NULL;
    int choice,data;

    while(1)
    {
         printf("\nPress 1 for inserting a node in BST fashion: ");
         printf("\nPress 2 for traversing the tree in preorder fashion :");
         printf("\nPress 3 for traversing the tree in postorder fashion :");
         printf("\nPress 4 for traversing the tree in inorder fashion :");
         printf("\nPress 5 to exit :");


         printf("\nEnter your choice: ");
         scanf("%d", &choice);

    switch(choice)
    {
        case 1: printf("\nEnter the data to be inserted:");
            scanf("%d",&data);
            insertnode( &root,data);
            break;

        case 2: preorder(root);
            break;

        case 3: postorder(root);
            break;

        case 4: inorder(root);
            break;

        case 5: exit(0);
            break;
        default: printf("\nYou have entered an invalid choice. Please try again");
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't know. I just posted my answer for the duplicate, which was slightly different. Your `&(pp)->lchild` et.al. looked wrong. Best way to know is to run diff -uw original.c newsource.c and look at the output. (remember: it's homework!)

Comment: I see you have directly used **p (double pointers). What is wrong with my approach of first storing them into single indirection pointers ?

Comment: Your version uses an extra variable, which later needs to be assigned to *p. Omitting it is simpler: fewer variables+assignments := fewer possibilities for error. BTW: I only use **pp only in sizeof; so **p is not a dereference in the strict sense, only its size is determined, not the object itself.

Comment: I understand, but i am more comfortable with that. Can you just see my code and tell me whether the statement struct treenode *p=&n; was right ?

Comment: No it is wrong (in the xxxorder() functions). It should be `struct treenode *p = *n;`. It is also useles, you could use (*n) in these functions in all the places where you now use n. (or change the function to take a pointer as an argument instead of a pointer-to-pointer)